# Confusion in 16-bit data-type range

Tags: c, char, int, range, primitive

In a 16 Bit C compiler we have 2 bytes to store an integer, and 1 byte for a character. For unsigned integers the range is 0 to 65535. For signed integers the range is -32768 to 32767.  For unsigned character, 0 to 255. According to the integer type, shouldn't the signed character range be like -128 to 127. But why -127 to 127? What about the remaining one bit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you're mixing two things:

1. What ranges the **standard** requires for `signed char`, `int` etc.
2. What ranges are **implemented** in most hardware these days.

These don't necessarily have to be the same as long as the range implemented is a superset of the range required by the standard.

According to [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), the implementation-defined values of `SCHAR_MIN` and `SCHAR_MAX` *shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value)* to, and of the same sign as:

```
SCHAR_MIN  -127
SCHAR_MAX  +127
```

i.e. **only 255 values, *not 256***.

However, the limits defined by a compliant implementation can be 'greater' in magnitude than these. i.e. `[-128,+127]` is allowed by the standard too. And since most machines represent numbers in the [2's complement form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement), `[-128,+127]` is the range you will get to see most often.

Actually, *even* the minimum range of `int` defined by the C standard is *symmetric* about zero. It is:

```
INT_MIN    -32767
INT_MAX    +32767
```

i.e. **only 65535 values, *not 65536***.

But again, most machines use [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) representation, and this means that they offer the range `[-32768,+32767]`.

While in [2's complement form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) it is possible to represent 256 signed values in 8 bits (i.e. `[-128,+127]`), there are other signed number representations where this is not possible.

In the [sign-magnitude representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method), one bit is reserved for the sign, so:

```
00000000
10000000
```

both mean the same thing, i.e. `0` (or rather, `+0` and `-0`).

This means, one value is wasted. And thus sign-magnitude representation can only hold values from -127 (`11111111`) to +127 (`01111111`) in 8 bits.

In the [one's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones.27_complement) (negate by doing bitwise NOT):

```
00000000
11111111
```

both mean the same thing, i.e. `0`.

Again, only values from -127 (`10000000`) to +127 (`01111111`) can be represented in 8 bits.

If the C standard required the range to be `[-128,+127]`, then this would essentially exclude machines using such representations from being able to efficiently run C programs. They would require an additional bit to represent this range, thus needing 9 bits to store signed characters instead of 8. The logical conclusion based on the above is: This is  why the C standard requires `[-127,+127]` for signed characters. i.e. to allow implementations the freedom to choose a form of integer representation that suits their needs and at the same time be able to adhere to the standard in an efficient way. The same logic applies to `int` as well.

Comment: By the way one of the speakers at this year's cppcon (I forgot which) said they were writing a paper on standardizing C++ on two's complement for signed integers.